# Soft keyboard hides on typing in Android EditText

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I have a couple of EditText fields on a form and when I start typing in either of them, the soft keyboard hides on each character input.

Is this something that is known and is there a way to handle this issue?
There doesn't seem to be anything special done to these fields to cause this issue.

I've googled for a solution, also browsed through various questions here, nothing helpful so far though.

Thank you.

Comment: `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustPan"`

Comment: can you post your code here

Comment: Not sure what code I can post really that could be useful..  So I have this in my AndroidManifest.xml: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden"`, and the EditText fields initialized with AndroidAnnotations, using @ViewById, and then the text in them is just read and validated when a Validation button is hit. Pretty much this concerning the fields.

Comment: I also tried `android:windowSoftInputMode = "adjustPan|stateHidden`, but to no effect either. I also thought that maybe this is an issue with the soft keyboard itself on Android, but it works correctly on other fields in other activities, and also it reproduces on Android 4.1.1, Android 4.2.2 and Android 4.4.4, so I guess that assumption is wrong.

Comment: Can you please post your edit texts code? You have a custom keyboard? Something appears on logcat?

Answer (score 1):

**you can try this**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

**or**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

**in manifeast file under your activity tab**

Answer (score 0):

Add following line

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"

in manifest under your that activity.

Answer (score 0):

it will work.

```
 <activity android:name=".Mainactivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"/>
```

add this in your manifest file